# Populate select options using jQuery and data attribute values

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add dates from a HTML list to a form.

To avoid changing the actual forms all the time I'd like to fetch the dates from text. Say I have a list with dates, if the user clicks the button that pops up the form I want to have the `<select>` in the form with the dates. (I do not intent to make every date clickable and pop up the form with the selected date)

So for example, my client edits the text of the page and adds the dates in the webpage text in a list like this:

```
<ul id="course1">
 <li>Date 1</li>
 <li>Date 2</li>
 <li>Date 3</li>
</ul>
```

In the text there's a button that opens a modal window with a form, all i want is to populate a `<select>` in that form with the dates from that list.

I managed to get it to work with just a normal text value like so;

HTML:

```
<a class="programma-kiezer" data-prog="Forming Fase" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="onderwijs">button</a>
```

And then it just takes the value of "data-prog" and puts it into the form

jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function () {

   jQuery('.programma-kiezer').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       jQuery('input[name="programma"]').val( jQuery(this).data('prog'));
   });
});
```

But how can I add option values from a list of dates and add those to the form?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the `<li>`s' texts and create `<option>`s for each of them.

Something like:

```js
$('#onderwijs').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  const dates = $('#course1 li').map((i, li) => $(li).text()).get();
  // dates = ['2020-12-05', '2019-09-05', '2028-05-04']
  let html = dates.map(date => {
    return `<option>${date}</option>`;
  }).join('');
  // html = <option>2020-12-05</option><option>2019-09-05</option><option>2028-05-04</option>
  
  $('#dates').html(html);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="programma-kiezer" data-prog="Forming Fase" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#onderwijs">button</a>

<ul id="course1">
 <li>2020-12-05</li>
 <li>2019-09-05</li>
 <li>2028-05-04</li>
</ul>

<div class="modal" id="onderwijs" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <select id="dates"></select>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Read more about

- [jQuery `map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) (`get` is returning a native javascript array).
- [javascript `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [jQuery `html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Let me know if something is not clear.